# Teste de Mesa em vetor Java

Tags: java, array, teste-de-mesa

Estou tendo dificuldade em resolver o teste de mesa do código seguinte, alguém poderia me mostrar a saída e como se faz?

```
public class Principal
{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

       int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       int aux[] = array;

       for(int counter = 0; counter < aux.length; counter++) {

          aux[counter]++;

       }

       for(int counter=0; counter < array.length; counter++) {

             System.out.println(++array[counter]);

       }

    }

}
```

O que eu entendi: Tenho um *array* (vetor) com 5 números com posições de 0 à 4. 
Tenho uma variável `aux` que é do mesmo tamanho do *array* (vetor).

Entendi que `array.length` é para pegar o tamanho do vetor, ou seja até o tamanho máximo do meu vetor, que nesse caso é `5`.

Não entendi: `aux[counter]++` dentro do **primeiro for**. Qual é sua verdadeira finalidade?

Estou ainda com um pouco de dúvida na hora de fazer o **teste de mesa**, pois quando pede `counter++`, eu nunca sei realmente o valor que coloco no teste de mesa.

Esse `counter++` manda somar o valor da minha variável counter ou manda eu pular tantas casas da variável? Ex:

```
counter = 0;

counter++;

counter = 1;
```

Dai eu pulo 1 casa e imprimo na tela o valor que está no espaço de memória 1 do contador, não é? Mas e quando o `counter` passa a ser 2? Eu conto a partir do 1 no espaço da memória ou a partir do 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegue entender isso?

```
aux[counter] = aux[counter] + 1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/Compound.java).

É a mesma coisa. Ele pega o valor do elemento indicado por `counter` do *array* `aux`, adiciona 1 e guarda no mesmo local, evidentemente mudando o valor desta variável.

O `counter++` apenas soma 1 à variável `counter`, não faz mais nada além disso. Não existe mágica. Não tem nada de "pular casas" ou coisa parecida. O operador funciona sempre na variável que está sendo aplicada, não funciona em outras coisas em outros lugares. O vetor é uma coisa e o contador é outra, por acaso em determinado momento eles são usados em conjunto para obter um resultado.

O termo "pular casas" aí me parece mal empregado. O `counter` é uma variável, e `aux` é outra, são coisas distintas. A variável `aux` tem um situação especial, ela não tem um só valor, tem vários. Normalmente chamamos cada um destes valores de **elementos** (algumas pessoas dão outros nomes, como itens, por exemplo, mas tem que tomar cuidado de não dar nomes que indiquem outra coisa que aquilo não é). Os elementos de `aux` são acessado por um índice numérico iniciando em zero para o primeiro elemento até um número antes do tamanho do vetor (já que começa do zero e não do um). Como vai acessar na memória é um problema que em Java não precisa saber, basta pensar abstratamente.

Você não pula casas, você acessa um elemento por um número. Este número pode ser um literal ou uma variável que indicará o seu valor. O acesso ao vetor é randômico, portanto acessa o que quiser, não é sequência pra ficar pulando nada.

Se não sabe qual o valor colocar no teste de mesa provavelmente está fazendo o teste de forma errada.

Teste de mesa é ir seguindo a sequência de execução do código como se fosse o computador e ter colunas (ou outra forma de organização) para cada variável e aí vai anotando o valor da variável sempre que ela muda. Você sabe que o valor atual é sempre o último, Isto deve simular a memória do computador.

Algumas pessoas preferem usar uma grade e repetir o valor de todas as variáveis em cada linha, tendo ela mudado ou não. Em geral isso "exige" uma marcação para indicar melhor quando houve alteração ou não.

Você pode estar pensando em como controlar os valores dos elementos do vetor, é simples: considere cada elemento como uma variável única, até porque no fundo é isso mesmo, são várias variáveis com o mesmo nome e um índice para diferenciá-las. Terá que que colocar no cabeçalho os nomes delas: `aux[0] | aux[1] | etc.`.

O valor atual do contador será usado pra determinar qual coluna você vai mexer. Se o contador vale 1, vai mexer na variável `aux[1]`, quando tiver que acessar para ler ou para mudar um valor de `aux`, terá que olhar o valor de contador, se ele for 2, por exemplo, sabe que manipulará a coluna `aux[2]`. Simples assim.

Tem um [exemplo de teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136393/101).

Comment: Ah entendi, obrigada...Muito boa a explicação. Vou tentar fazer aqui. ;)