# Como fazer Teste de Mesa para determinado algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo, pseudocódigo, teste-de-mesa

Tenho esse algoritmo, em um pseudocódigo:

Sabendo que n1 recebe o valor 20.

```
inicio 
inteiro: n1,n2,n3; 
leia (n1); 
n2<-n1*3; 
n3<-n1-1+n2; 
imprima("O resultado final será n3=",n3); 
fim.
```

Exemplificando:

> **n2** **<-** (Recebe resultado) de **n1*3**(20 vezes 3)

Como fazer um Teste de Mesa para achar o resultado deste algoritmo acima?

Comment: pt.slideshare.net/mobile/henriquecarmona/aula-4-teste-de-mesa

Answer (score 8):

Cada um adota uma técnica própria de fazer o teste de mesa. Vou descrever mais ou menos como eu faço.

Crio uma tabela com as variáveis declaradas, cada uma em uma coluna. Cada linha da coluna servirá para anotar o novo valor da variável sempre que houver uma [nova atribuição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101). Algumas pessoas gostam de riscar o valor anterior para evitar confusão e só deixar visível o última mesmo, que é o que vale.

Também é possível ter colunas para sub-expressões, o que pode ajudar achar erros nelas.

Então a partir da terceira linha começo a anotação ma coluna de `n1`. Vou anotar um valor que desejo testar.

Em seguida anoto o resultado do cálculo do valor de `n1` (é sempre o último valor disponível na coluna) vezes 3.

Aí faço o mesmo pegando o último valor de `n1` menos 1 mais o último valor de `n2`.

Depois anoto em separado o que deve aparecer na tela (uma página só para demonstração de tela), no caso `O resultado final será n3=` e o último valor de `n3`.

Se fosse algo mais complexo continuaria. Se tivesse um laço iria mantendo as anotações.

Eu testaria com vários valores, com 0, positivo, negativo, alguns números altos, tentaria por um texto, enfim tentaria criar situações que provoquem erro no algoritmo.

Para fazer um teste de mesa fácil é importante o algoritmo não ser grande demais.

Em alguns casos pode haver algumas especificidades de como proceder.

Algumas pessoas gostam de criar uma linha de dados para cada linha ou sub-expressão executada copiando os dados anteriores. Eu acho exagero, mas pode ser útil em alguns casos. Só faço algo quando muda o estado.

Ferramentas de *debug* poderosas existentes hoje quase aboliram o uso do teste de mesa na mesa mesmo :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Resolução do problema:

Sabendo que **n1** recebe o valor **20**, fiz a atribuição, dessa maneira:

---

```
inicio               
inteiro: n1,n2,n3;   //Declaração de Variáveis
leia (n1);           //Entrada de Dados
n2 <-20*3            //Processamento    
n3 <-20-1+60         //Processamento 
imprima("O resultado final será n3=",n3); // Saida
```

O resultado será: 79

---

Teste de Mesa

| Linha | n1 | n2 | n3 | soma | Subtração | Produto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 20 | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| 4 | 20 | ? | ? | ? | ? | 60 |
| 5 | 20 | 60 | ? | 79 | 19 | ? |
| 6 | 20 | 60 | 79 | ? | ? | ? |

Veja conforme a atribuição dos valores e com a resolução do algoritmo encontrei o resultado.

Fiz esse Teste de Mesa com base nesse [link](http://pt.slideshare.net/mobile/henriquecarmona/aula-4-teste-de-mesa).

Comment: Na coluna (Subtração) linha 5, o correto não seria informar -1, já que 19 seria parte do resultado da linha 5? Imagino que a forma que foi colocada pode gerar dúvida.