# Não estou entendendo loops while aninhados

Tags: python, loop, while

Estou com dificuldade em compreender esse código, pois não entendo como ele se comporta nos *loops* `while`, segue as instruções depois do código.

Obs 1: Estou aprendendo logica de programação ainda, por isso estou "batendo cabeça" com códigos simples.

Obs 2: O código está correto, eu só preciso de entender o fluxo do código.

Obs 3: o '#' com o número no código representam as perguntas.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

primeira = []
segunda = []
terceira = []

while True:
    e = int(input("Digite um valor para a primeira lista (0 para terminar):"))
    if e==0:
        break
    primeira.append(e)
while True:
    e = int(input("Digite um valor para a segunda lista (0 para terminar):"))
    if e==0:
        break
    segunda.append(e)

duas_listas = primeira[:]
duas_listas.extend(segunda)

x=0
while x < len(duas_listas): #1
    y = 0
    while y < len(terceira): #2
        if duas_listas[x] == terceira[y]:
            break;
        y=y+1 #3
    if y == len(terceira): #4
        terceira.append(duas_listas[x])
    x=x+1
x=0
while x < len(terceira): #5
    print("%d: %d" % (x, terceira[x]))
    x=x+1
```

1 - Nessa primeira verificação eu entendi porque a lista contem dados, então pra mim faz sentido `x` ser menor que o comprimento da lista.

2 - Aqui, como `y` que é 0 (zero) pode ser menor que o comprimento da lista "terceira" sendo que a lista "terceira" é vazia?, ou seja, zero é menor que zero?

3 - Por que o código não incrementou o `y=y+1` sendo que `y=y+1` é a próxima linha após o `break`.

4 - Se o método `len()` faz a contagem partindo do número 1 quando contêm dados dentro de uma lista, quando uma lista não contêm dados o seu valor e zero?

5 - Aqui eu entendi, o *loop* `while` passa por cada item na lista "terceira" e imprime o valor de cada item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - Nessa primeira verificação eu entendi porque a lista contem dados, então pra mim faz sentido `x` ser menor que o comprimento da lista.

ok

> 2 - Aqui, como `y` que é 0 (zero) pode ser menor que o comprimento da lista "terceira" sendo que a lista "terceira" é vazia?, ou seja, zero é menor que zero?

Na primeira passada isto é verdade na segunda pode não ser mais já que logo abaixo pode ter um `append()` na lista:

```
if y == len(terceira): #4
    terceira.append(duas_listas[x])
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ConditionalAppend.py).

> 3 - Por que o código não incrementou o `y=y+1` sendo que `y=y+1` é a próxima linha após o `break`.

Está incrementando, desde que entre neste laço

> 4 - Se o método `len()` faz a contagem partindo do número 1 quando contêm dados dentro de uma lista, quando uma lista não contêm dados o seu valor e zero?

Isso.

> 5 - Aqui eu entendi, o *loop* `while` passa por cada item na lista "terceira" e imprime o valor de cada item.

ok.

Faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136393/101) no algoritmo e vai entender melhor. Pode fazer com um *debugger* e ver passo a passo o que vai acontecendo.