# Obter nomes de uma lista que possuem tamanho igual a 4

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte problema: a partir de uma lista de nomes, preciso retornar somente os nomes com `len` 4.

Escrevi o código abaixo mas aparentemente o *loop* não está funcionando visto que, em uma lista com 4 nomes, sendo dois dentro do critério, ele só retorna um.

```
def nomes(x):
    for i in x:
        y = len(i)
        nome = []
        if y == 4:
            nome.append(i)
    return nome
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa inicializar a lista fora do laço, do jeito que está fazendo cada item analisado está começando a lista do zero e perde o que já tinha feito. Sempre que encontra um problema analise o que o código está fazendo. Vai explicando o que ele faz linha por linha, faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136393/101).

```
def nomes(x):
    nome = []
    for i in x:
        if len(i) == 4:
            nome.append(i)
    return nome
    
print(nomes(["abc", "jose", "ana", "maria", "joao", "abcd"]))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bdlAh4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vaaatvng-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/InitListInLoop.py).

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo.

Answer (score 3):

Para referências futuras, você pode resolver em uma linha, com um código equivalente, utilizando a chamada compreensão de lista:

```
def nomes(lista, tamanho):
    return [nome for nome in lista if len(nome) == tamanho]
```

A função recebe a lista de nomes e o tamanho desejado, que neste caso seria 4; percorre todos os nomes da lista e se o tamanho coincidir com o tamanho desejado, adiciona-o à lista de saída.